# Dropdown Value from DB Entry

Tags: dropdown

I am capturing a month in my database and the value (integer) is being recorded but when I try to add the selected to the drop down so when the user comes back it reflects the month I can't figure out what I need to set the drop down to reflect the integer value that was previously submitted.  If someone can share what i am missing in my selected code I would really appreciate it.

```
    $months = array(
        1=>'January',
        2=>'February',
        3=>'March',
        4=>'April',
        5=>'May',
        6=>'June',
        7=>'July',
        8=>'August',
        9=>'September',
        10=>'October',
        11=>'November',
        12=>'December'
    );

    $birth_date_month = get_the_author_meta( 'birth_date_month', $user->ID );

    <?php
    foreach ( $months as $num => $month ) {
        printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $month, selected( $birth_date_month, $num, false ) );
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It's not possible to tell what the value of `birth_date_month` would be from the code you've given, the save code would be necessary. But since you have access to the code, could you not just do `echo $birth_date_month` and look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually outputting the `selected` attribute into the `<option>` tag. Look at your `printf()` format:

```
'<option value="%u">%s</option>'
```

`%u` is there for the month's number value, and `%s` is there for month's name, but you're not including the last argument from the result of `selected()`.

Your `printf()` needs to look like this:

```
printf(
    '<option value="%u" %s>%s</option>', 
    $num, 
    selected( $birth_date_month, $num, false ), 
    $month
);
```

Note that I swapped the order of the arguments, because `selected` needs to be output before the month name.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  That was exactly what it needed.